# Can cars legally drive in the bike lane down the street?

Tags: legal, bike-lane, bike-vs-car, california

Every day on my way to school there is a long street with a bike lane and two car lanes on each side. But when the street is jammed I have cars going really fast behind me and honking because I'm not going 45 miles an hour like their car is. Can they really do this? I mean it's the BIKE lane. It's one thing to be pulling out of a parking spot and crossing the bike lane but to be driving on it in general shouldn't be right. I live in Los Angeles, CA.

Comment: Where do you live? What do you mean by "pure bike lane and 2 car lanes on both sides"?

Comment: and on left side there are two car lanes and a bike lane and on the right two car lanes and a bike lane.

Comment: Obviously they *can* do it, since they do.

Comment: To the person close-voting: This site has decided that certain localized questions are on-topic here.

Comment: When I first moved to a new city, I got pulled over for driving in a bike lane one time. It had the same width as a regular lane, and so many people were doing it that I didn't even realize that it was a bike lane. Now that I know better, I wish the officer was out there pulling people over more often.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. In California, a car can only drive in a bike lane 200 feet before making a turn from that side of the road or when entering or exiting the road.

[California Vehicle Code 21209](http://www.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/vctop/d11/vc21209.htm)

Comment: thank you. im new to this site and i love that there are people here to help.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE! Don't forget to accept the answer, so the author gets credit.

Comment: +1 freiheit, that's interesting. In the UK it all depends on how the bike lane is marked. Solid white line means no traffic, dashed line makes it optional. Does the US have the concept of solid/dashed at all?

Comment: @Pete -- The US has numerous concepts surrounding solid/dashed.  Unfortunately, they vary by state, and no one understands them anyway.

Comment: @Dan -- excellent. The great thing about standards is that there's so many to choose from!

Comment: yes U.S. has solid lines (can't cross over at all) and dashed lines (means you can change lanes or pass cars). AFAIK they are standard across every state I've driven in.

Comment: @dotjoe -- But there are different variations of dashed lines -- long vs short.  And not one driver in ten even understands the distinction between solid and dashed.

Comment: In California: A solid white line means cars generally shouldn't be crossing it (used for the shoulder/fog line, turn lanes at intersections, etc). A dashed line is used for the marking between lanes, where merging across the line is expected. A bike lane is indicated with a solid white line that's slightly wider than the line used for the edge of the road (shoulder/fog line). Bike lanes are usually dashed for the last 50 feet, to indicate that bikes going straight should merge left.

Comment: @DanielRHicks didn't even know about long and short dashes...roads are pretty old by me. We do have a ton of new roundabouts but I don't want to go there.

Comment: @dotjoe -- Nobody wants to go through the new roundabouts (especially cyclists).

Comment: (Short dashes signal that the lane nearest the curb is a turn lane.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks - that's strange. Solid vs. dashed is covered in every drivers exam manual I ever seen.

Comment: @DVK - How long has it been since most drivers read a driver's manual?

Answer (score 2):

The clue's in the name.  BIKE lane!  If you see cars doing this, especially if you're being bullied by antisocial car drivers, I'd recommend taking notes of license plates and having a few friendly chats with the police.  Realistically that probably wouldn't achieve much, but you never know.

Comment: The questioner says he's in LA.  If he's in the city of Los Angeles (as opposed to Los Angeles County) the anti-harassment ordinance might come in handy: http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jul/21/local/la-me-bicycle-law-20110721

Comment: @nickg -- Yeah, but what if it's a driverless car?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: LA anti-harassment ordinance is civil, not criminal. With witnesses, you can sue whoever is responsible for the driverless car.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - if it's a driverless car, it probably is harrassing you because you didn't click on enough ads (or aren't using Google Maps to navigate).